# Using fread() to read binary data one record at a time

Tags: c, struct, fread

It says The fields of the records are stored using the types specified in the data file description. The fields are stored packed next to each other in the data file. You cannot read the entire record directly into a C struct in one call because C inserts additional unused space between some of the fields in the struct (this is called alignment padding.

You must read the data record one field at a time. It is suggested to use fread to read each field.

My code reads a struct record of various data types. filename is f1.

I have tried 2 methods

First method:

```
fread(&rec1, sizeof(struct record), 1, f1);
```

Second method:

```
fread(&rec1.tin, sizeof(struct record), 1, f1);
printf("%hhu, ", rec1.tin);
fread(%rec1.love, sizeof(struct record), 1, f1);
printf("%s, ", rec1.love);
fread(&rec1.curve, sizeof(struct record), 1, f1);
printf("%d, ", rec1.curve);
fread(&rec1.history, sizeof(struct record), 1, f1);
printf("%lu, ", rec1.history);
fread(&rec1.ground, sizeof(struct record), 1, f1);
printf("%u, ", rec1.ground);
fread(&rec1.week, sizeof(struct record), 1, f1);
... and so on
```

None of the above work for me as test file returns

```
**** Automarker: fread must read each struct field separately
```

**** Output ignored.  Your program exited with error code: 202

Comment: The data `rec1.tin` (etc.) is *not* the size of the whole record.

Comment: The assignment clearly states that the first method will not work owing to padding between struct fields, which is not reflected in the arrangement of data on disk.  Your second method looks okay, but you're asking `fread` to read too much on each call.  Check the `man` page for `fread`, and look at the interpretation of the second argument, relative to what you're passing as the first argument.

Comment: The suggestions in the previous comments would lead to, for example: `fread(&rec1.tin, sizeof(rec1.tin), 1, f1);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. this works perfectly. now fread reads one struct entry at a time.